# I m trying to backup my sqlite database file from local storage to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-sqlite, firebase-storage

I m using Firebase as my primary database, some of the local data is storing into sqlite.
I m trying to backup and restore my sqlite db file from local storage to Firebase Storage... I have uploaded the file and now i want to restore it into the same package/databases directory... but couldn't figure it out.

```
// uploading SQLITE.DB file to FIREBASE STORAGE

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath") String inFileName = "/data/data/com.example.casebook/databases/EVENTS_DB.db";

Uri localDB = Uri.fromFile(new File(inFileName));

        final StorageReference DBRef = storageReference.child("users/"+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/EVENTS_DB.csv");
        DBRef.putFile(localDB).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FILE UPLOADED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


// downloading SQLITE.db file from FIREBASE STORAGE

        DBRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

// here i want to get the "EVENTS_DB.db" file to the exact same path "inFileName" for restoring the same DB with help of FIREBASE STORAGE.

            }
        });
```

Comment: There's not really enough information here to understand what isn't working the way you expect with the code you've shared.

Comment: This code is to upload the EVENTS_DB.db file from "inFileName" path to Firebase Storage.
The file is Successfully uploaded... but now i dont know how to download it back to same "inFIleName" path from Firebase Storage if i want to restore the sqlite database

Comment: Please **edit the question** to add more details.  There is an edit link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: i have edited it, is it ok?